# How to set order by created date in mongodb query using sails js

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am little familiar with sails and mongoDB, Here i want to know how to sort the data while selecting from collection in DESC order.

Here i enclosed my controller function:

```
listall : function(req, res){
        var userId = req.session.passport.user;
        User.find().sort( { '_id': -1 } ).where({
            id: userId
        }).exec(function(err, data) {
            Listing.find().where({
                userid : userId
            } ).exec(function(err, listdata){
                console.log(listdata);
                res.view('dashboard/listing', {
                'userdata': data,
                'userlisting' : listdata
            });
            });

        });
```

Here my sorting is not done, it fetch the rocord in ASC order.
Please guide me where i am doing mistake.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What does your `_id` field look like in your documents?

Comment: its autogenerate while insert

Comment: Yes but "what does it look like?". Something like this: `ObjectId("55ded957c9064ef625d7f35d")`? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> Heads up
>
> sails-mongo maps the logical id attribute to the required _id
>   physical-layer mongo id. In the current version of sails-mongo, you
>   should not sort by id.

See the sails-mongo [Documentaion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mongo)